# React not Updating View after State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a basic calculator and my solution is Making a history array and then running it through a loop to compile the result however I am getting a problem where on updating the History array the view does not update

```
    function CalcBuilder() {
    function WriteNum(number) {
        let TempHistory = History;

        TempHistory.push(number);

        setHistory(TempHistory);
        console.log(History);
    }

    const [
        History,
        setHistory,
    ] = useState([
        0,
    ]);

    let CalcItems = [];
    CalcItems.push(
        <h1 key='display' className='displayed'>
            {History.toString()}
        </h1>,
    );
    CalcItems.push(
        <h1 key={1} className='element' onClick={() => WriteNum(1)}>
            1
        </h1>,
    );
    function Add() {
        let TempHistory = History;
        TempHistory.push('+');
        setHistory(TempHistory);
    }
}
    return <div className='grid'>{CalcBuilder()}</div>;
```

Why is this ocurring do I need to somehow manually update the JSX or is it a problem with the Code it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that `TmpHistory` is a reference to `History`, so modifying it is the same as modifying `History`, and React does not like when you modify state objects directly.

Instead make of a copy of `History` in `WriteNum` and `Add` like this:

```
 let TempHistory = [...History];
```